# Moving Files from Path in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, shutil, fnmatch

I have a folder with about 600,000 photos in it. I need to move a select 500 of those photos.  I have a dataframe with those file paths as values in one of the columns.  I need to be able to loop through that data frame, pluck out the specific image and set it in another folder.

The path is the full path to include the file.  There is also a file column that has just the file name.

The following is an example of the data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'path': ['D:\\images\\train\\roof\\1.jpg', 'D:\\images\\train\\roof\\2.jpg', 'D:\\images\\train\\roof\\3.jpg'
                  ,'D:\\images\\train\\roof\\4.jpg', 'D:\\images\\train\\roof\\5.jpg'],
        'image': ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg',]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df
```

The following is what I tried. It's a modified version of moving files based on a wild card.

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch
def gen_find(filepat,top):
    for path, dirlist, filelist in os.walk(top):
        for name in fnmatch.filter(filelist,filepat):
            yield os.path.join(path,name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = df['path'] # input
    dst = 'D:\\images\\Sample' # desired     location

    filesToMove = gen_find(src)
    for name in filesToMove:
        shutil.move(name, dst)
```

I also tried the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = 'D:\\images\\train\\roof\\'+df['image'] # input
    dst = 'D:\\images\\Sample' # desired     location

    filesToMove = gen_find(src)
    for name in filesToMove:
        shutil.move(name, dst)
```

Comment: What reaction do you get? Is there an exception or what happens?

Comment: I get this:. `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Series`

Comment: Print the first entry coming from your gen_find function! Try a debugger e.g. pycharm and set a breakpoint to the yield instruction. Look at the arguments you pass into the os.path.join